# page reloaded when i click the button

Tags: sharepoint-online, html

I used following accordion code, But my page reload or refresh when i click it.

```
<body>
<h2>IT Teams</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons to open the collapsible content.</p>
<button class="accordion">USA</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Jose Andrew</p> 
  <p>Edward Gee</p>   
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything is the script that is causing the reload. Can you share the markup for the "accordion" that they are clicking on?

Comment: Sure , I attached it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `type="button"` to your `<button>` tag to stop the reload:

`<button class="accordion" type="button">`

Comment: Some more information, as the answer is a bit short:
As per https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element the default type of a button element is the "submit" state (like if specified as `<button type="submit" />`), which will submit the current form. The type "button" defaults to doing nothing.